# Syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am hitting up an API, and when there is nothing returned, it was throwing a "no method for `nilClass`" error. So I added a bunch of `if`/`else` statements to handle that. Below is my code.

Now I'm getting an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end
```

Because it was working, I think my routes are fine. I marked the line in the view below that is causing the error.  When I remove that `end`, it still throws errors:

**main_controller.rb**

```
def money
    @first = params[:first_name]
    @last = params[:last_name]
    @politician = JSON.load(open("http://..."))
        if @politician.empty?
            @politician = "Enter a politician's name."
        else
            @year = params[:year]
            @pol_id = @politician[0]["id"]
            @breakdown = JSON.load(open("http://..."))
                if (@breakdown["Individuals"]).nil? 
                    @individuals_money = 0
                    @individuals = 0
                else 
                    @individuals_money = (@breakdown["Individuals"][1]).to_f 
                    @individuals = @breakdown["Individuals"][0]
                end
                if (@breakdown["PACs"]).nil?
                    @pacs_money = 0
                    @pacs = 0
                else
                    @pacs_money = (@breakdown["PACs"][1]).to_f
                    @pacs = @breakdown["PACs"][0]
                end
            @total_money = @individuals_money + @pacs_money
            @top_contributors = JSON.load(open("http://..."))
     end
   end
```

**money.html.erb**

```
    <div class = "col-md-6">

        <% if @politician == "Enter a politician's name." %>
            <br />
            <p><%= @politician %></p>
        <% else %>
            <h3><%= @politician[0]["name"] + " for " + @year %></h3>
            <p><%= number_to_currency(@total_money) + " Total received"%></p>

            <p><%= number_to_currency(@individuals_money) + " from " + number_with_delimiter(@individuals, :delimiter => ',') + " contributors" %></p>
            <p><%= number_to_currency(@pacs_money + " from " + @pacs + " PACs" %></p>

            <h4>Top Contributors</h4>
            <% y = 0 %>
            <% for y in 0..9 %>
                <p><%= (y+1).to_s + ". " + @top_contributors[y]["name"].to_s + " " + number_to_currency(@top_contributors[y]["total_amount"].to_i) %></p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %> <<<<==== ***This is the line throwing the error***
    </div>
```

Comment: You are missing an `end` for `if else` in `money` method

Comment: Things like `if (@breakdown["PACs"]).nil?` are bad form, it leads to your `else` being a double negative ("If *that* is not not defined"). It would be better expressed as `if @breakdown["PACs"]` with the clauses reversed.

Comment: Also worth noting if your indentation was fixed this error would be more obvious. You eventually get used to the patterns Ruby creates with `if`-`end` pairs.

Comment: @Vimsha the extra 'end' accidentally got cut off when copy/pasting my code. Thanks, I have corrected in the code above. I wish that was it!

Comment: why is this getting downvoted?  i tried to solve this for two hours on my own and thought SO was a place where we go to get help?  it's not like i didn't try on my own.  sheesh.

Comment: Usually "help syntax error" type questions aren't very popular since they're *extremely* specific and are less likely to help other people in the future. I've bumped you up a bit +1, just doing my part!

Comment: @tadman - okay, thanks for explaining that. it's frustrating as a new person to work for hours and then come here and get downvoted.  thanks for the up!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your syntax error on this line:
`<p><%= number_to_currency(@pacs_money + " from " + @pacs + " PACs" %></p>`

There's no closing parenthesis for `number_to_currency`.  It should be:

`<p><%= number_to_currency(@pacs_money) + " from " + @pacs + " PACs" %></p>`

Comment: holy crap, that was it!  thank you so much.  i spent hours today staring at this code and couldn't understand why i was getting this 'end' error.  now i know that it can literally be anything.  thanks for helping a newbie.  :)

Comment: Been there myself, friend.  The "expecting ')'" part of the error message was your biggest clue:  look for a '(' without a ')' and you've found the error - at least that's been my experience with these syntax errors.  It usually has nothing to do with the line number the error was found on.  That's just the line of code where the lack of ')' presented a problem.

Comment: wow, thanks. i guess i didn't realize that. i will certainly be on the look out for those in the future. thanks again for taking the time to help me and offer explanations!